# Append XmlElement below another XmlElement

Tags: c#, xml

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();

string soapEnvelope = 
@"<s:Envelope  xmlns:s=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"">
<s:Body xmlns:xsi=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance""      xmlns:xsd=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"">
 <ExternalProcessingStatusUpdate xmlns=""http://tempuri.org/"">
  <deliveryId>12232</deliveryId>
  <success>true</success>
  <message>Completed</message>
  </ExternalProcessingStatusUpdate>
  </s:Body>
 </s:Envelope>";


doc.Load(new StringReader(soapEnvelope));

//Create a new node.
XmlElement elem = doc.CreateElement("orderId");
elem.InnerText = "ORDER_994865453";

XmlNode root = doc.DocumentElement;

var nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
nsmgr.AddNamespace("rate", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema");
var node = doc.SelectSingleNode("//rate:ExternalProcessingStatusUpdate", nsmgr);

doc.InsertAfter(elem, node.FirstChild);
```

I want to insert a new element "orderId" after "deliveryid" element in the above Xml string .How can i solve this issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ExternalProcessingStatusUpdate` has default namespace (`xmlns="..."`), so it and it's descendant elements without prefix are in that default namespace. This means, the new element `orderId` should be declared in that namespace too, otherwise it will be created in no namespace, like `<orderId xmlns="">`, which I assume not something that you actually want :

```
//Create a new node in "http://tempuri.org/" namespace
XmlElement elem = doc.CreateElement("", "orderId", "http://tempuri.org/");
elem.InnerText = "ORDER_994865453";
```

Then you are supposed to call `InsertAfter()` on the parent of the new node :

```
var nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
nsmgr.AddNamespace("rate", "http://tempuri.org/");
var deliveryId = doc.SelectSingleNode("//rate:ExternalProcessingStatusUpdate/rate:deliveryId", nsmgr);

deliveryId.ParentNode.InsertAfter(elem, deliveryId);
```

**<kbd>[`dotnetfiddle demo`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Gepua8)</kbd>**

Comment: @SagarJagadesh you're welcome! and don't forget to [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) the answer